# Odoo - error in query outside http request

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

When I try select records from (for example) res.user like this:

```
with api.Environment.manage():
    registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name)
    with registry.cursor() as cursor:
        environment = api.Environment(cursor, None, {})
        environment['res.user'].search([])
```

I get an exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/models.py", line 4200, in _generate_order_by
    order_by_elements = self._generate_order_by_inner(self._table, order_spec, query)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/models.py", line 4167, in _generate_order_by_inner
    raise ValueError(_("Sorting field %s not found on model %s") % (order_field, self._name))
ValueError: Sorting field model_id not found on model ir.rule
```

So it happens with any models. But everything is fine if I make a request in the controller method or in the method of the model

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try:

```
with api.Environment.manage():
    registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name)
    with registry.cursor() as cursor:
        environment = api.Environment(cursor, SUPERUSER_ID, {})
        environment['res.user'].search([])
```

I Just included the superuserid, hoping this is preventing the access of models